# How do I change the host ID on Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-9.10

On an Ubuntu 9.10 machine, how do I change the host ID to a different value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to compile and run a small program to do that.

See the following two threads:

[howto change the hostid under linux](http://www.edaboard.com/ftopic281551.html)
[Hostid in a Linux machine](http://www.edaboard.com/ftopic42754.html)